# Display current date in xsl

Tags: sharepoint-server, xslt, rss

I would like to display current date with the following format. However using current-date() is throwing error "Failed to apply XSLT" 
Thu 02 Mar 2017

The following is the code that i have so far. Thank you

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="x d xsl msxsl cmswrt"
  xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
  xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" 
  xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/Publishing/runtime"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:w="http://rss.weather.com.au/w.dtd">

  <ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />




<xsl:template match="/">



<div id="top" >


        <div class="weather rendered">

            <xsl:attribute name="onclick">OpenPopUpPage('<xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/link"/>')</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="title">Current temperature: <xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/item/w:current/@temperature"/>° &#xD;City forecast for <xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/item/w:forecast[1]/@day"/>:&#xD;<xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/item/w:forecast[1]/@min"/>&#176;-<xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/item/w:forecast[1]/@max"/>&#176;, <xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/item/w:forecast[1]/@description"/></xsl:attribute>

            <div class="max"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(/rss/channel/item/w:current/@temperature, '0')"/><span class="deg">&#176;</span></div>

            <div><xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@CurrentDate) ,1033 ,'MMM yyyy')"/></xsl:value-of> </div>

        </div>



</div>
</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note:**
if I used the following it work fine, but it will display date in GMT not local date which is 11 hours ahead.

```
  <div class="date"><xsl:value-of select="substring(/rss/channel/item/pubDate,1,16)"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below:

```
<xsl:value-of select="formatDateTime(string(/rss/channel/item/w:current/@dateFieldParameter) ,1033 ,'MMM yyyy')"/>
```

This must work for you..

Comment: i have updated the question as your suggestion but still not working

Comment: kindly add whole xslt of your data view web part..this might help in targeting the error

Comment: i am not using dataview webpart. I am using XSL to read rss feed. that is the whole xsl. thanks

Comment: can u now try please...replace dateFieldParameter by parameter name from RSS feed

Comment: Thanks Ankitkumar, the problem is i need to get local timezone. The current pubDate in RSS using GMT. Local timezone is 11 hours ahead. That is why i want to achieve using currentDate function which not available in XSLT 1.0